# Problem using createActions instead of createAction with redux-actions

Tags: redux, redux-actions

I have a problem when I use a **createActions**, if only use **createAction** all works but if i try to use createActions the app show me a error ....

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function

In all my functions that has a dispatch method, only works with createAction

```
import { createAction, createActions } from 'redux-actions'
// Types
import { ADD_TASK } from '../types/todo.types'
import { SHOW_TASKS } from '../types/todo.types'

// export const addTaskAction = createAction(ADD_TASK)
// export const showAllTasksAction = createAction(SHOW_TASKS)

// * Refactor to createActions

export const { addTaskAction, showAllTasksAction } = createActions(
  ADD_TASK,
  SHOW_TASKS,
)
```

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function
_callee$
src/shared/routes/private/PrivateRoutes.routes.js:19
  16 |   getAllTasks()
  17 | }, [])
  18 | 
> 19 | async function getAllTasks() {
     | ^  20 |   const result = await todo.getAllTasks()
  21 |   return dispatch(showAllTasksAction(result))
  22 | }
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me and the issue was that the constants need to match the actions (with camelcase) that way the createActions function can match the action with the string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).